# GLSL Atomic Counters segfault when reading

Tags: c++, glsl

Recently I got a segfault when reading atomic counters via glMapBuffer. Here is the code:

```
GLuint atomicCounter[2];

inline void getAtomicCounters()
{
    glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, ATOMIC_COUNTER_INDEX, acBuffer);
    CHECK_FOR_GL_ERRORS();
    static GLuint* data = (GLuint*)glMapBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
    CHECK_FOR_GL_ERRORS();
    atomicCounter[0] = data[0];
    atomicCounter[1] = data[1];
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER);
    CHECK_FOR_GL_ERRORS();
}
```

The problem seems to be that data is a static pointer. When I remove the static keyword, everything works perfectly. I know that I don't need a static pointer, it was just a test and I'm quite surprised that it won't work with a static pointer. Does anybody know why a segfault occurs at "atomicCounter[0] = data[0];"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not at all surprising.

Do you understand how a variable declared with the `static` qualifier in the body of a function works in C++? It will be initialized with that value the first time the function (`getAtomicCounters (...)`) runs, but each subsequent execution will skip-over the initialization:

```
 static GLuint* data =
   (GLuint*)glMapBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
 //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 //This is only evaluated the first time you call this function!
```

So every subsequent call is going to use the value of `data` you initialized the first time. The elephant in the room is that the value of `data` became invalid when you made this call:  **`glUnmapBuffer(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER);`**

You can fix this simply by assigning `data` the return value of `glMapBuffer (...)` on a separate line from the one where you declare the variable. Then it will always execute `glMapBuffer (...)` when you call this function.

However, to be completely honest, I can see no reason why you would need or even ***want*** `static` storage for your `data` pointer.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I wasn't aware of the skipping, I thought that the variable would just persist in memory. I usually don't use static variables inside functions, only as members of classes. That's why the problem never occurred to me. And of course I won't use a static variable for this type of problem, but for counters inside functions. I thought that if you assign a value which can't be evaluated at compile time (like the function call above), the skipping wouldn't take place.